# Посоветуйте книгу по грамматике русского языка

Tags: грамматика

Наткнулся на данный форум, когда безуспешно прошерстил несколько онлайн-библиотек и магазинов в поисках книги, которая даст полное представление о грамматике русского языка. Цель поиска - саморазвитие. О себе: 18 лет, 1 курс технического университета.

Comment: Для начала воспользуйтесь этой книгой.

Comment: @Серж какой книгой?

Comment: простите, забыл ссылку дать. https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/

Comment: @Серж благодарю

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вам хочется доступной литературы, обратите внимание на две книги В. Н. Мусатова:

1. Мусатов В.Н. «Русский язык. Фонетика. Фонология. Орфоэпия. Графика. Орфография».
2. Мусатов В.Н. «Русский язык. Морфемика. Морфонология. Словообразование».

В вашем распоряжении есть и более тяжелые для восприятия труды, такие как [Русская грамматика – 80](http://rusgram.narod.ru/) и [Русская корпусная грамматика](http://rusgram.ru/).

Comment: Aer, Корпусная грамматика и Грамматика-80 все же предназначены для специалистов. Простым пользователям понять ее трудно.